# javascript && evaluate

Tags: javascript

here is javascript code:

```
var test = {
    "h" : function (a) {return a;},
    "say" : "hello"
};
```

First run:

```
test['h'] && true
```

result is true

second run :

```
true && test['h']
```

result is function()

my question is, why first run and second run produce different result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last truthy argument of `&&` is returned. (If there is a non-truthy argument, false is returned, of course.) That's just how `&&` works.